# ShellScript não executa 'cd', chamando o sh via php

Tags: php, linux, shell-script, powershell

tudo bem?
Veja se alguem ja passou por isso, estou com esse simples código em shellscript, que acesso a pasta (/home/teste4toquew5824) e depois confirmo se entrei no diretorio com pwd,

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/teste4toquew5824 && pwd
```

e tenho um arquivo php (localizado em /var/www/html) que chama esse sh:

```
    $retorno = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/api/teste.sh');
    echo "<br><br>";
    var_dump($retorno);
```

Quando recebo o retorno do pwd ele mostra como se ainda tivesse no diretorio do arquivo php (/var/www/html), ou seja ele não ta "aceitando" ou executando o comando cd.

1 - Jà apliquei permissões para o php e para o sh.

2 - Jà confirmei o diretorio /home/teste4toquew5824 existe

3 - já testei e coloquei um echo dentro do sh só para confirmar que o php está chamando e executando o sh corretamente.

4 - Já coloquei no sh uma linha para copiar um arquivo só para ter ceteza que outro comando está sendo executado tambem e copiou o arquivo para /var/www/html

Alguem tem alguma ideia?
Muito obrigado

Comment: Troque o shebang do script de `#!/bin/bash` para `#!/bin/sh -` .Bash não aceita `pwd`.

Comment: troquei aqui, mesmo assim não rolou :( parece que não ta entrando na pasta

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar um echo no script ficando dessa forma.

> cd /home/teste4toquew5824 && echo $(pwd)

Comment: nada viu, continua imprimindo NULL :(

Answer (score 0):

Tente alterar para:

$retorno = shell_exec('. /usr/local/bin/api/teste.sh');

Isso força executar o comando dentro do seu processo atual.

Comment: Testei aqui agora, não rolou :(

Comment: Você consegue mudar o diretório atual de execução do processo utilizando chdir, por exemplo:

chdir(' /home/teste4toquew5824');

Veja se isso serve pra você.

Answer (score -1):

Olá...
Tente desta maneira: Jogue o path numa variável.
Por vias, não sei qual user vai rodar então carregue o profile e externamente ao script, confirme se tem permissão.

Depois execute o `cd` chamando a variável, exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile
path=/home/teste4toquew5824
cd $path
```